# Consulta que hereda dos veces de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
Select
    v.id_user, 
    uv.nombre_nacion as PaisEnvia,
    up.nombre_nacion as PaisRecibe
From 
 solicituds as v
 INNER JOIN pais as uv on v.id_pais_envia = uv.id_nacion
 INNER JOIN pais as up on v.id_pais_recibe =up.id_nacion;
```

Sería eso mismo pero en Eloquent

Comment: La idea es mostrar primero lo que se ha intentado y con mucho gusto procedemos a colaborar/corregir lo que sea necesario.

Comment: Buenas tardes entiendo pero no tengo idea de como hacer eso en laravel con eloquent

Comment: La idea es mostrar al menos el más mínimo avance, si entendiste como usar Laravel, seguro entiendes al menos algo básico de Eloquent.

Comment: Esto parece algo que puedes resolver con [relaciones de Eloquent](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) . Prueba a ver la de **One To Many** y **One To Many (Inverse)**

Comment: seria algo asi
$pedido=DB::table('solicituds as v')
                   ->select(
                          'solicituds.id_user as PaisEnvia,',
                          'solicituds.id_pais_envia PaisRecibe',
                          'solicituds.id_pais_recibe'
                          )
                    ->join('pais as uv','v.id','=','uv.id_nacion')
                    ->join('pais as up','v.id','=','up.id_nacion')
                    ->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo logre era este codigo

```
$pedido=DB::table('solicituds as v')
                   ->select(
                          'v.id_user',
                          'v.id_pais_envia',
                          'v.id_pais_recibe',
                          'av.nombre_nacion as PaisEnvia,',
                          'ap.nombre_nacion as PaisRecibe'
                          )
                    ->join('pais as av','av.id_nacion','=','v.id_pais_envia')
                    ->join('pais as ap','ap.id_nacion','=','v.id_pais_recibe')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Esta solución no es con Eloquent, es con el Query builder, de hecho es más sencillo con Eloquent y las relaciones.